# $area is not returning the correct value in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, area

[image]

I'm working in a black QGIS project set to EPSG:27700 and a layer in EPSG:2770. When I measure the area of a polygon using the measure tool I get a value of 7594315ha. When I subsequently do this in the field calculator using `$area/10000` to return the value in hectares I get a value of 3. I'm not sure why this is so small as I've never had an issue with this before and both project and layer are in the same projection.

Comment: what does the yellow warning box say? Can you maybe add a larger screen shot so we can see some detail

Answer (score 2):

This was solved by going to Project>Properties>General and changing units for distance measurement to meters rather than square miles which had come in as default.